# SQL CE in WP7 Mango - Datatype mapping from SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, linq, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce, sqldatatypes

I found a msdn doc on recommendations for mapping datatypes between sql server 2008 and sql ce 3.5 in .NET. This actually shows a color coded matrix. **Unfortunately I am not able to find the link to it now.**

However, that doc recommended to use VARCHAR(MAX) / NVARCHAR(MAX) and DATETIME2 so that when .NET converts them to string & DateTime, they would ***better match*** the datatype limits. It was said that the (MAX) will be converted to (4000).

But when I tried to use them to define the ColumnAttribute in a DataContext use of (MAX) and DATETIME2 were giving compilation and runtime errors. So, I reverted to (1000) and DATETIME.

Now this doc on "[Differences Between SQL Server Compact and SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896140%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)" tells that DATETIME2 is supported in both SQL CE 3.5 & 2008.

When I try to search for "sql ce 3.5 compatibility with wp7", I am not getting any useful document.

Is there any help doc detailing the datatypes allowed in SQL CE 3.5 for WP7 and how they map to SQL Server 2008 datatypes?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the page you're after is [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171931.aspx).  SQL CE 3.5 is the same no matter what platform you're on, so the "WP7" part of the question doesn't matter.

Comment: It was not this that I was looking for. That one had a colored matrix showing the mappings. Anyway this doc indicates that DateTime2 is available in SQL CE 3.5 SP1. As I was getting run-time errors, I suppose WP7.1 doesn't have SP1 of CE 3.5. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I've just been looking for this myself and came across this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172424(SQL.110).aspx

Looks like WP7 uses SQL CE 4.0 and we need to stick to datetime and ntext.

EDIT: I found the link above on this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202872(v=VS.92).aspx

Comment: Actually, WP7 uses SQL Server Compact 3.5

Comment: That's what I thought as well but the link in the msdn documentation (the bottom link in my post) points to the data types in 4.0 - add to this the fact that datetime2 isn't supported makes it look like only the 4.0 types are supported.

Comment: The 3.5 and 4.0 types are the same!

Comment: OK, found this link and now I understand - datetime2 is mapped to an nvarchar(27) value (I was pretty confused about the actual type mapping before I found this): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171931(v=SQL.100).aspx